# What mean the parameter np on mpi?

Tags: mpi

I am learning MPI and I want to know, if the parameter -np on mpi has some relation with the number of processors of my computer. I am starting with the documentation of MPI and I have found this

> Open MPI provides both mpirun and mpiexec commands. A simple way to
>   start a single program, multiple data (SPMD) application in parallel
>   is:
>
> 1 shell$ mpirun -np 4 my_parallel_application
>
> This starts a four-process parallel application, running four copies
>   of the executable named my_parallel_application.

When I execute the follow command in my Ubuntu 12.04

```
less /proc/cpuinfo
```

I obtain 4 processors with 2 cpu cores each one (At the end of this question you can find part of the output of that command). My question: using SMPD, is the command.

```
mpirun -np 4 my_parallel_application
```

copying each program to each processor of my computer? or where is realized this each copy.

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 37
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 480  @ 2.67GHz
stepping        : 5
microcode       : 0x2
cpu MHz         : 1197.000
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi     flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 5320.03
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 37
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 480  @ 2.67GHz
stepping        : 5
microcode       : 0x2
cpu MHz         : 1197.000
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 2
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 4
initial apicid  : 4
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge   mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 5320.03
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 2
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 37
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 480  @ 2.67GHz
stepping        : 5
microcode       : 0x2
cpu MHz         : 1197.000
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 1
initial apicid  : 1  
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 5320.03
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 3
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 37
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 480  @ 2.67GHz
stepping        : 5
microcode       : 0x2
cpu MHz         : 1197.000
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 2
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 5
initial apicid  : 5
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 5320.03
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: Your CPU has two physical cores and two hardware threads per core for a total of four hardware threads. Whether your program will run better with two MPI processes (`-np 2`) or with four (`-np 4`) depends mainly on whether it is compute-bound or not. `mpirun -np 4` starts four copies of the program as four separate OS processes from the same executable. It is the same as starting four times a text editor - you get four separate windows where you could work independently from one another. MPI then allows those four separate processes to exchange data via messages.

Comment: @HristoIliev please post an answer not a comment

Comment: @kukis, I do not consider my comment an answer. It only contains pointers to information that the OP might want to research him-/herself.

Comment: @HristoIliev How do you onow that exist two physical cores and two hardware thread per core? which part of my post say you that?. See that my question say that when I run less /proc/cpuinfo I get 4 processors, but in the question I only paste one and part of the second, but there are 2 more.

Comment: @HristoIliev I have edited my question adding the whole output of the command less /proc/cpuinfo

Comment: @HristoIliev then my program, when is run using -np=4, is copied in each four hardware threads?

Comment: @user46060, it's not rocket science. One just has to look up your CPU model (i5-480M) in [Intel ARK](http://ark.intel.com/products/52952/Intel-Core-i5-480M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_66-GHz) to find out the specs.